# Why is bundle --deployment trying to rebuild gem ffi-1.9.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, ffi

I've run bundle --deployment on a machine with a full dev environment, and then copied the vendor/bundle to a second machine not having the full dev environment. On the second machine, a simple 'bundle exec irb' gives:

/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

```
/usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.1 extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib64/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Isn't bundle --deployment meant to copy the entire gem, including any native binaries? Why is it trying to rebuild?

On the dev machine, libffi43, libffi-devel and libffi43-devel are installed, and on the non-dev machine, only libffi43 (libffi43-4.3.4_20091019-0.37.28) on SUSE SLES SP3.

Comment: your ruby versions are the same? `ruby  -v` on the two machines returns exactly the same version?

Comment: Yes, ruby -v on both give 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux-gnu]. However, I just noticed that the Linux kernel on one has advanced from 3.0.1.101.0-35 to 3.0.1.101-0.40. Is that enough to cause this?

Comment: I have this problem recently. But in my case I had installed ruby 2.0.0-dev a long time ago (about six months ago), when FFI was not intend to be part of ruby core. Happens that I had updated to 2.0.0 and so I got this message. The problem in my case was that gem think that 2.0.0-dev and 2.0.0 are compatible (because the last versions of 2.0.0-dev have ffi, but not the first ones) and try to reuse the 2.0.0-dev gems, which don't really have ffi. In my case I had solutioned by removing ruby completely (with rm -Rf ~/.gem) and reinstalling with rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built up a dev system with the same kernel, and this solved the problem. I would not have thought the slight difference in the kernel would cause the failure. I may have overlooked some other small detail that fixed it, but I doubt it.